# Is it redundant to index against a field used for a partition?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a few massive tables that I need to partition. I've learned from [the "SQL and Database Explained!" series on partitioning](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJMaoEWvHwFJxaF-wWcvvnAcP9kZiLkkX) that my optimal partitioning approach will be via a interval partition:

```
...PARTITION BY RANGE(start_date) INTERVAL(NUMTOYMININTERVAL(1, 'YEAR')...
```

The table getting partitioned will be queried with filters against the `start_date` field:

```
SELECT columns
FROM My_Table
WHERE start_date BETWEEN SYSDATE-90 AND SYSDATE
ORDER BY start_date;
```

**Is it redundant to index against a field used for a partition?** In my case, since I will be partitioning against `start_date`, will there be additional benefits if I also index on the `start_date` column?

Answer (score 4):

Excellent question. The answer depends on the range of dates you will be querying vs. the partitioning interval, and whether you have an Exadata or a conventional Oracle database.

If you don't have Exadata, your partitions are yearly, and you ask for a few days, you will still benefit from a local index on the date column. That's because the cost of scanning that entire year worth is likely more than doing an index scan and pulling the rows by ROWID from the index for just a few days' worth.

But, if you (1) do have Exadata, or (2) your partitions are monthly or smaller and your queries are for a day or more, or (3) you have yearly partitions and you are asking for a month or more in your query, then no, you do not need nor want an index on the date column. The cost of using an index in those situations is potentially much greater than the cost of scanning the partition segment(s).

I would suggest that you partition by month and not by year. Too many queries will probably be asking for much less than a year's worth, and you don't want to have to scan a lot of unnecessary segment blocks. You want partition pruning to prune as much as possible, so a smaller interval will help here. Going smaller than a month will only help if your queries are asking for less days than are in the month.

Comment: Your advise is too generic. I have a table with daily partition. Per day it has around 6 Billion records. A missing index on the date column would kill the database, even for Exadata. The queries are based on a hour value.

Comment: <3 for the "excellent question". As I typed it, I was wondering to myself "is this too remedial? Does everyone else know the answer to this?"

Comment: Regarding "partition by month and not by year"...I have 22 years worth of data, and growing. So partitioning by month would require 264 partitions already...which would take a bite out of the Oracle limit of...looking it up...1,048,575 partitions. So that's...87,381 years. Nevermind.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit, I was speaking to OP's situation which is a 22-year table that gets queried by several months at a time. If you have a unique situation with many concurrent users that would swamp your resources unless you throttle them by forcing them to use inefficient index access, slowing them down but reducing the overall load on your system, well, there's a use-case for nearly everything I suppose. But if you don't have a concurrency/resource issue, a single query for an hour's worth of data on a daily-partitioned Exadata table would be much better off without an index.